# How to import Angular Material Css

Tags: angular-material, angular-material2, angular-material-5

I'm trying to use Angular Material in my project and the tags are imported, but not all of the styling is there.

In my HTML:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker startView="year" [startAt]="startDate"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

It should show:

[image]

But it shows:

[image]

I added `@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";` to styles.css and the calendar is showing fine, but the text field still looks bad.

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to follow everything here. https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Try adding this line to your styles.css: `@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";`

As from this step: https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-4-include-a-theme

These are the imports you will need:

```
import { MatDatepickerModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatNativeDateModule, MatInputModule } from '@angular/material';

import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';


@NgModule({    
imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, MatDatepickerModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatNativeDateModule, MatInputModule, BrowserAnimationsModule],
...
})
```

Comment: I added the style and the datepicker shows fine, but the input-text is not styled.. I will add a screen shot to the question. Do you know what I can do to fix that?

Comment: Check my updated answer. Notice the `MatInputModule` import. If you still have trouble check this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wzbq2t

Comment: :) Imports are a bit disconcerting at first, but you'll get the hang of it in no time!