# Angular standalone Dialog not getting styled

Tags: javascript, angular, dialog

I'm trying to make a standalone dialog for my Angular app that can be used throughout the application.  The dialog appears like it should, but no styling is being applied.  The dialog code is:

```
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'app-confirmation-dialog',
  templateUrl: './confirmation-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./confirmation-dialog.component.scss'],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatButtonModule
  ]
})
```

And the template code is:

```
<h4 mat-dialog-title>Confirm</h4>
<div mat-dialog-content>
    {{message}}
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
    <button (click)="yes()" color="primary">Yes</button>
    <button (click)="no()" color="alert">No</button>
    <button (click)="cancel()" color="warn" *ngIf="showCancel">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

The resulting dialog looks like this:

[image: Dialog]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think you need ".css" file, not ".scss" which would need to be compiled.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50856861/17038313

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use one of the Angular Material pre-built themes (the easiest solution by far), refer to [Using a pre-built theme](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#using-a-pre-built-theme). Also make sure to select the correct Angular Material version in the toolbar.

Your `styles` array in `angular.json` should look like this:

```json
"styles": [
  "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
  "src/styles.scss"
],
```

By the way, this code can be inserted automatically with `ng add @angular/material`, which prompts you about theming, typography and animations.

Also, I see that you forgot to add `mat-button` to your `button` elements.

Here is a revised template:

```html
<h4 mat-dialog-title>Confirm</h4>
<div mat-dialog-content>
    {{message}}
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
    <button mat-button (click)="yes()" color="primary">Yes</button>
    <button mat-button (click)="no()" color="alert">No</button>
    <button mat-button (click)="cancel()" color="warn" *ngIf="showCancel">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The mat-button did it.  I knew it was something dumb that I just wasn't seeing.